# Nullpoint Exception - ImageLoader

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-activity

While trying to load the following activity, I ran into a NullPoint exception, I tried resolving the issues but my attempts have been unsuccessful.

In brief, there are two activities- one that populates a list of arrays and upon click of an item in the arrays list takes the user to a second activity page (this one) that populate more information about that item. My issue have resolve around in populating images through JSON in the second activity.

Below is the logcat message:

```
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 5085
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:233)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:171)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.loadImageIfNecessary(NetworkImageView.java:140)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.onLayout(NetworkImageView.java:180)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onLayout(HorizontalScrollView.java:1474)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-28 23:35:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(5085):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

First Activity Code

```
public class CasualEventsActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/casual.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;
    public Uri list_item_bac;
    public String list_item_name;
    public String list_item_description;
    public String list_item_location;
    public String single_list_item_description;
    public String list_item_price;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();


        GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsActivity.this,CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_title());
                intent.putExtra("list_item_location", container.get(position).getList_item_location());
                intent.putExtra("single_list_item_description", container.get(position).getSingle_list_item_description());
                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        });
    }
    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_location = obj.getString("list_item_location"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String single_list_item_description = obj.getString("single_list_item_description");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id, list_item_location, single_list_item_description,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
}
```

Second Activity Code

```
public class CasualEventsSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_price;
    String list_item_location;

    String single_list_item_description;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);


        RequestQueue mRequestQueue = null;
        ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });


        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_location = i.getStringExtra("list_item_location");



        single_list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_description");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView txtsdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdescription);


        NetworkImageView hsvimage1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage2 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage3 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);

        // Get image URLs from your previous network request...
        // I could not determine where this is stored from code in your question.
        String url1 = "I would want to populate the list_bac JSON string that links to a image URL";   // e.g. http://example.com/images/image1.png
        String url2 = "I would want to populate the list_bac JSON string that links to a image URL";
        String url3 = "I would want to populate the list_bac JSON string that links to a image URL";

        // Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
        // specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
        hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage2.setImageUrl(url2, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage3.setImageUrl(url3, mImageLoader);


        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtlocation.setText(list_item_location);
        txtsdescription.setText(single_list_item_description);


        Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConfirm2);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

               // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();

                currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 
                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                   }
               });
                //CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, MatchingActivity.class));
            }
        });









    }
```

Second activity layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_bac3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="0.01"
        android:textColor="#82CAFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="0.01"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dividertop"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/location"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/divider11"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dividerbottom"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vsvdescription"
       android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/divider11"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/isgallery"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dividerbottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage1"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:padding="1dp" />
               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage2"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="1dp" />
               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage3"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#CCC"
                android:padding="1dp" />
               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage4"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="1dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                  </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bConfirm2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/isgallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bac"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#2B3856"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vsvdescription"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" 
        android:padding="5dp"       

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dividertop"
         >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sdescription"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Update

```
public class CasualEventsSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_price;
    String list_item_location;

    String single_list_item_description;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);


        ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(this),
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });


        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_location = i.getStringExtra("list_item_location");



        single_list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_description");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView txtsdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdescription);


        NetworkImageView hsvimage1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage2 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage3 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);

        // Get image URLs from your previous network request...
        // I could not determine where this is stored from code in your question.
        String url1 = "list_item_bac";   // e.g. http://example.com/images/image1.png
        String url2 = "list_item_bac";
        String url3 = "list_item_bac ";

        // Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
        // specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
        hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage2.setImageUrl(url2, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage3.setImageUrl(url3, mImageLoader);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtlocation.setText(list_item_location);
        txtsdescription.setText(single_list_item_description);


        Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConfirm2);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

               // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();

                currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 
                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                   }
               });
                //CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, MatchingActivity.class));
            }
        });









    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well this is the code for where you are getting your NPE

```
  * Constructs a new ImageLoader.
     * @param queue The RequestQueue to use for making image requests.
     * @param imageCache The cache to use as an L1 cache.
     */
    public ImageLoader(RequestQueue queue, ImageCache imageCache) {
        mRequestQueue = queue;
        mCache = imageCache;
    }
```

so why are you passing a null for the first argument?

```
Also as per the code
/**
 * Helper that handles loading and caching images from remote URLs.
 *
 * The simple way to use this class is to call {@link ImageLoader#get(String, ImageListener)}
 * and to pass in the default image listener provided by
 * {@link ImageLoader#getImageListener(ImageView, int, int)}. Note that all function calls to
 * this class must be made from the main thead, and all responses will be delivered to the main
 * thread as well.
 */
```

So I would take their advice and use `ImageLoader.get (String requestUrl, final ImageListener listener)`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and for helping me resolve my issue with nullpointer. The other related issue I have resolves around displaying the images through JSON data, where instead of having String url3 = "image.com/image.png", I would have String url3 = "list_image1 ";, where list_image1 refers to a JSON string that links to an image url, and where the JSON link can be found at for example website.com/json.php  I have added the updated code under the update section of my initial post. If you could kindly look into it, that would be helpful. Thanks